# Si può dire "avere vinta" invece di "averla vinta"?

Tags: word-usage, idioms

Alla [voce "averla vinta" del dizionario De Mauro](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/averla-vinta) ho trovato questo esempio:

> *è sempre difficile avere vinta con te*.

Si tratta di un refuso e dovrebbe essere invece "è sempre difficile averla vinta con te"? Oppure si può usare "avere vinta" al posto di "averla vinta"?

Comment: Mai sentito l’espressione “avere vinta” con senso di “averla vinta.” Google Books mostra una serie di usi di “avere vinta” dove il pronome viene usato prima tipo: “la vuoi avere vinta” o “spera di poterla avere vinta” etc. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22avere%20vinta%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1949,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Si tratta di un refuso e dovrebbe essere invece "è sempre difficile averla vinta con te"?

Sì, si tratta di un refuso.

La Dott.ssa Francesca Ferrucci della redazione del dizionario Nuovo De Mauro ringrazia per l'interessamento al dizionario e la segnalazione, che ha consentito di correggere il refuso.